# How to export language file content to CSV in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, export-to-csv

CodeIgniter has the language class by default. I want to export all the language file into CSV format. Is there any PHP script available to parse and export the file content?
Sample file content:

```
<?php 
$lang['Mymenu'] = "Mymenu"; 
$lang['AdminUser'] = "AdminUser";
```

The language files can also be placed inside the folders like

```
application/language/english
application/language/spanish ...etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution from the gist
https://gist.github.com/timneutkens/19e58a00ff8af4663c6502a1d89990a4

Thanks for that but the solution not applicable for recursive language directories.

Here I am posting the modified version:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP version 5.4
 * @category Export
 * @package  Language
 * @author   Tim Neutkens <tim@weprovide.com>
 * @license  MIT <https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT>
 * @link     <weprovide.com>
 */

define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
/**
 * Placeholder for base_url function
 *
 * @param string $path path part of url
 *
 * @return string
 */
function base_url($path = '')
{
    return '/'.$path;
}

/**
 * Placeholder for base_url function
 *
 * @param string $path path part of url
 *
 * @return string
 */
function site_url($path = '')
{
    return '/'.$path;
}

/**
 * Export csv to file location
 *
 * @param array $data csv data
 * @param string $location location to put file
 *
 * @return string
 */
function export_csv($data = [], $location = '',$file_name)
{
   // $file_name = 'export-lang-'.time().'.csv';
    $file_name = $file_name.'.csv';
    $file_path = $location.'/'.$file_name;
    $file      = @fopen($file_path, 'w');

    fprintf($file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        fputcsv($file, [$key, $value]);
    }

    fclose($file);

    return $file_path;
}

/**
 * Load language
 *
 * @param string $path path to language directory.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function load_language($path = '')
{
    // Loop through translations
    /*$files = glob($path.'/*.php');
    foreach ($files as $filename) {
        include_once $filename;
    }*/

    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    if(!is_dir($filename))
      include_once $filename; //echo $filename . ' - ' . $file->getSize() . ' bytes <br/>';
    }

    return $lang;
}

$lang_array = array('arabic','chinese','english','french','german','italian','japanese','korean','polish','portuguese','russian','spanish','turkish','vietnam'); // List of language folders
$i=1;
$file_arr = array();
$lang1 = $lang2 = $lang3 = $lang4 = $lang5 = $lang6 = $lang7 = $lang8 = $lang9 = $lang10 = $lang11 = $lang12 = $lang13 = $lang14 = '' ;
foreach ($lang_array as $language) {

    ${"lang" . $i} =  load_language('application/language/'.$language);
    export_csv( ${"lang" . $i} , '/xampp/htdocs/CodeIginiter/language',$language);
    // Lang gets filled by the above includes
    $i++;
}
```

Place the file in the root directory of CodeIgniter and execute. CSV files will get downloaded which can easily export to excel and used for language translators.

Comment: Just want to share the knowledge!